# React, Redux, NodeJS Оставаться в система после обновление страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

У меня есть приложение react + node js

в нем есть следующий функционал

1. можно создать новый аккаунт

2. после чего можно войти, ввести свой email и password

После того как пользователь вошел то есть (/login) node js возвращает jwt токен, а также обьект пользователя

токен я сохраняю в localStorage, а обьект пользователя сохраняю в redux store

вопрос следующий, после того как пользователь зашел и обновил страницу (нажал f5) у меня остается только его токен в localStorage обьект user конечно же нет так как store redux был сброшен

насколько я делаю правильно что бы пользователю не пришлось снова вводить имя и пароль, я отправляю токен из localStorage запросом get в headers после чего node js проверяет этот токен не прошел у него срок годности, если все ок возвращает мне обьект пользователя?

на сколько это правильно ведь можно просто скопировать токен из localSorage Вставить его в другом браузере и мое приложение автоматически даст вам доступ на закрытые странцы?

Comment: ну вы делаете все правильно. Да скопировать можно, но для этого нужен прямой доступ к компьютеру и именно к браузеру. С точки зрения безопасности, если у кого-то есть прямой доступ к компу, то тогда тут далеко не до `jwt` токенов)

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо вам за ответ

Comment: все верно. Скопировать jwt может либо человек, имеющий доступ к браузеру, либо вредоносный скрипт, работающий на вашей странице. Обычно jwt делают короткоживущими, чтобы не было смысла их красть. Для защиты можно добавлять в payload jwt уникальные данные, типа ip клиента, user-agent браузера и т.д. чтобы токен примененный из другого места стал невалидным